# Is there any evidence that the RigVedic seers were aware of what would be called "Satvik food" today?

Tags: rig-veda, food

The Rig Veda - the foundational scripture of Hinduism is said to have been directly"seen" by its authors and not composed.  They carried out animal sacrifices and the meat of the sacrificed animals was eaten.

In present day Hinduism there is the notion of "Satvik food" which avoids animal products, sometimes including dairy also.

Were the Rig Vedic seers unaware of "Satvic food"?